# Taylor expansion for $1/(1+x^2)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

In the book **Short Calculus** The author, in order to prove the taylor series for the arctangent, he presented the taylor expansion of $$\frac{1}{1+x^2}$$

Which is (the one of the author):$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} =1-x^2+x^4-x^6+...+(-1)^{n-1}x^{2n-2}+(-1)^{n}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^2}$$

But using long division, I’ve found a slightly different one:
$$\frac{1}{1+x^2} =1-x^2+x^4-x^6+...+(-1)^{n}x^{2n}+...$$

Which one is correct? This is an important thing because it will change the remainder term of the taylor expansion for the arctangent.

Comment: Did you mean in your expression to write an infinite sum? if yes you get exactly the same expression as above.

Comment: How? They are different

Comment: $$\dfrac{d(\arctan x)}{dx}=?$$

Comment: The author's equation is correct for all values of $n$; your formula is not correct for any (finite) $n$, only in the limit as $n\to\infty$ (and then only for $|x|\lt1$).

Comment: If $\frac{1}{1+x^2} = 1 - x^{2} + x^{4} - ... = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} x^{2n}$ then you can also write $ 1 - x^{2} + x^{4} - x^{6} .... +(-1)^{n} \frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2}} = 1 - x^{2} + x^{4} .... + (-1)^{n} x^{2n}  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} x^{2k} =  \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{j} x^{2j} + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k+n} x^{2k+2n}= \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{j} x^{2j} +\sum_{k=n}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} x^{2k} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n} x^{2n}$.

Comment: There are the same, but different versions the author series is more defined, it breaks the series and takes it to $2n-2$ then continue with the structural form, while your series continues to $\infty$

Comment: @Yassir Aren't you missing a "$+\ldots$" at the end of your expression?

Comment: The first one is a Taylor polynomial, with remainder; whereas the second one is a Taylor series.  I guess when you say "Taylor expansion" you could mean either one?  The Taylor polynomial with remainder is true for all $x$, whereas the Taylor series is true only for $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expansion is based on the high-school identity:
$$1-x^n=(1-x)(1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1})$$
which can be rewritten as
$$\frac 1{1-x}=1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{n-1}+\frac{x^n}{1-x}.$$
Now substitute $-x^2$ to $x$ in this formula, and you obtain exactly the formula in the book.

Other than that, you also can obtain the same result, not by long division, but by the division along *increasing powers*  of $1$ by $1+x^2$. As an example, here is this division up to order $8$:
\begin{array}{rcl}
&&\phantom{-}1-x^2+x^4-x^6 \\
1+x^2&\Bigl(&\phantom{-}\not1 \\
&& -\not1-x^2 \\
&& \phantom{-1}\enspace+x^2 +x^4\\
&& \phantom{-1\enspace+x^2} -x^4- x^6\\
&& \phantom{-1\enspace+x^2 -x^4}+ x^6+x^8\\
&& \phantom{-1\enspace+x^2 -x^4+ x^6}+x^8\\
\end{array}
So the remainder at order $8$ is $x^8$, and this division means that
$$1=(1-x^2+x^4-x^6)(1+x^2)+x^8\implies\frac 1{1+x^2}=1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\frac{x^8}{1+x^2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}\frac1{1+x^2}&=\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-x^2)^i 
\\&=  \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-x^2)^i +\sum_{i=n}^\infty (-x^2)^i \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-x^2)^i +(-x^2)^n\sum_{i=0}^\infty (-x^2)^i \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (-x^2)^i +\frac{(-x^2)^n}{1+x^2}\end{align}

You can also view it as:

$$\frac{1-(-x^2)^n}{1-(-x^2)}=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}(-x^2)^i$$

where you can replace $-x^2$ by $r$, and get the geometric sum.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different ??

Both Taylor expansions are

$$\sum_n(-1)^nx^{2n} $$ (summation limits omitted on purpose).

Your expression is just missing the remainder term.